# How could an aquatic animal’s organ evolve so it could live outside water?

Tags: evolution

How could a fish’s organs evolve so that it could one day live outside of water.

I mean did it one day fully evolve then stick its head out of the water. That would mean that all the evolution of that fish would have needed to happen while it was essentially under water. But I can't see how that it is possible to convert from aquatic to semi-aquatic while living in the water.

Surely its organs would fail while only living in the water but having dual-function lungs and other organs.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. In particular, note the [homework rule](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) - So, what do you know about evolution of the lung? As a hint, you might want to investigate respiratory systems in fish, particularly Lungfish.

Comment: look at fish that live in swamps they breath air because the water is so low in oxygen. we think lungs and legs both evolved in the water.

Comment: Which organs? the skin is watertight in most fish to prevent dehydration to saltwater. the only organs exposed to air are the eyes, skin, and whatever they breath with. if you look at US one of those is watertight and the other two constantly lose water.

Answer (score 1):

It may surprise you to learn that *most* bony fish are capable of breathing air, not just the lungfish and mudskipper.  If you have ever seen a fish in a muddy lake looking like it's blowing bubbles on the surface, that is what was happening.  It was breathing.  Oxygen levels in the water can be super inconsistent, and many fish species need to be able to supplement that oxygen with oxygen from the air in order to survive.  If you ever get a betta, make sure it can make it to the surface because it will straight up *drown* if you don't.  The way they tend to do this is via the swim bladder.  The swim bladder is already almost a simple lung.  It can hold gas and exchange it with the blood.  All you need to make it a basic lung is a tube that connects it to the mouth.  Throw in some branches and ridges for surface area and you have a full on lung right there.  Some fish can fill the air bladder directly by gulping air.  Others gulp it into the stomach and then diffuse it into the air bladder, but most fish can breath air to some degree, even if they never come out of the water.  Fish that do come out of the water, like lungfish, do so using a modified swim bladder, one with a tube and some nifty ridges that lets it function as a full lung so the fish can go for a walk when its pool dries up.  From there, it's just more ridges, more pockets, more surface area, better tubes, basic optimization that evolution is real good at.  The line from swim bladder to lung is actually one of the straighter ones when it comes to evolutionary history.  There are definitely some winding roads but this isn't one of them.